# Why some apps can't access internet using wi-fi?

Tags: applications, wi-fi, internet

I've been trying to update several antiviruses, they can't find server. Duck Duck Go app can't access internet too. Google Play and Chrome works fine. I'm using wi-fi shared by my laptop, in properties: WAP & WPA2 Personal, mode -infrasturcture.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any proxy settings to access your WiFi? (proxy settings might be provided by your network provider). Most of the apps can't access the proxy settings provided by the android. For resolving that you can use [ProxyDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid) app (but it needs root-access).

Comment: Is there an antivirus that works ok with these settings ?

Comment: @RS No, all/most of the antivirus apps can't access the system's proxy settings. You need root access for that. So rooting your device is the only option.

Comment: @Vamsi, if all/most, then the answer is "probably". I had no proxy settings. What should I type in there ?

Comment: @RS Please check your internet settings. You are able to access internet in your laptop right? So go to internet options in your laptop (open control panel->internet options->connections->lan settings). What do you mean by  wifi shared by your laptop? Did you create a hotspot in your laptop?

Comment: @Vamsi, my laptop has internet connection via cable, I share it with my android by Wi-Fi, I'm using Ubuntu (I did like this http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/share-internet-with-android-ubuntu-1404/)

Comment: @RS As I mentioned earlier, check your connection settings for the proxy configuration. If there are no proxy configurations, then I'm not sure whether I can  help you.
Do you need to enter any credentials to access the internet?

Comment: There are no proxy configs. I entered only WAP & WAP2 at Wi-Fi

Comment: Try using [avast](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.avast.android.mobilesecurity&hl=en) it is a freeware. Check whether it is connecting to internet or not.

Comment: I've been tryed avast, avg, northon, bitdefender, trustgo, avria.

Comment: Avast is confusing, after updating it tells that you have the latest version, it seems it cares about antivirus version but not antivirus database.

Comment: just for the reference, connect from different mobile to your hotspot.

Comment: I do not have such an opportunity.